# Mapping a small properties object to large properties object

Tags: c#, .net

I got two objects with some properties as follows:

```
public class Person 
{
  public string DoctorId { get; set ;}
  public string DoctorName { get; set;}
  public string PersonId { get; set;}
  public string PersonName { get; set;}
}

public class SaveRequest
{
  public string DoctorName { get; set;}
  public string PersonName { get; set;}
  public string PersonId { get ; set;}
}
```

Now as you can see, I want to map the `SaveRequest` to `Person` Object I have. We do this by `PersonId` which is the key and also my requirement as you see is, not all properties are in `SaveRequest`, its just name of person and doctor and `PersonId` just for primary key...

Please help me as to how to map these in C# with a small code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try using a mapper like [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/)

With automapper, you'll have to

- Add a reference using nuGet (`PM> Install-Package AutoMapper`)
- Then create a map using `Mapper.Initialize(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<Person, SaveRequest>());`
- Then, simply use the mapper like so: `SaveRequest sr = Mapper.Map<SaveRequest>(person);` where `person` is an instance of `Person`
- More info here (https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Flattening)

Or you could build your own custom Mapping method which takes in a `Person` and returns/maps the data to a `SaveRequest`

Or you could simply use Person and ignore the `DoctorId` property wherever you intended to use `SaveRequest`

Comment: Thank you, could you pls write a bit of code using automapper for me to understand, I am new

Answer (score 1):

Automapper is a library that aims to make this type of thing much easier, however it's more suited for use in multiple areas within a project rather than just one isolated case (otherwise it'll take longer to set it up than it's worth).  http://automapper.org/

The old school way is to just do it by hand, property by property.

One could write a routine using reflection that would examine property names and match the values, but if you go that far, you might as well just use Automapper, is that's exactly what it does (and a lot more).

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, could you pls write a bit of code using automapper for me to understand, I am new